# The integrand function in integral is a non numerical problem

Tags: numerical-integration

The expression for $f\left( x \right)$ is known as follows:

$$
f\left( x \right) =\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
    e^x,0\le x\le 1\\
    0\ ,others\\
\end{array} \right. 
$$

The following equation needs to be solved: $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{dx}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f\left( x \right) f\left( y-x \right) dy} $

By solving manually (We can manually simplify the upper and lower limits of the integral):$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{dx}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f\left( x \right) f\left( y-x \right) dy}
$$
$$
=\int_0^1{\int_x^{1+x}{e^xe^{y-x}}dxdy=\left( e-1 \right) ^2}
$$

Can't get a result using `Integrate`.

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := Exp[x] /; 0 <= x <= 1;
f[x_?NumericQ] := 0 /; x < 0;
f[x_?NumericQ] := 0 /; x > 1;
Integrate[
 Integrate[f[x] f[y - x], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}], {x, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}]
```

Modified to use `NIntegrate`, although the result is correct, there is an error message saying that the producted function is non-numerical, how should the error be corrected?

```
NIntegrate[
 NIntegrate[f[x] f[y - x], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
```

> 2.95249

```
N@(E - 1)^2
```

> 2.95249

Comment: Use: ``f[x_] := Piecewise[{{Exp[x], 0 <= x <= 1}}]; Integrate[
 f[x] f[y - x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]``

Comment: Since you call two separate `NIntegrate`s for the `x` and `y` integration, the inner `NIntegrate` has to numerically integrate w.r.t `y` with symbolic `x` in the integrand.

Comment: `f[x_] := Exp[x] Boole[0 <= x <= 1];`works too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exchanging the integrals (the integrand is absolutely integrable), the inner integral is a convolution and therefore we can write:

```
f[x_] = If[0 <= x <= 1, Exp[x], 0];
Integrate[Convolve[f[y], f[-y], y, x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(-1 + E)^2
```